# Flutter: Deleting widget with delete icon from a list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a form builder application, I have stateless widgets which get added to list view, each widget has a delete icon, I want to delete the widget and update the list view.
[image]

one of the code widget code is this

```
class HeaderTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onDelete;

  HeaderTextWidget({Key key, this.onDelete}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text(
              'Header',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: Colors.blueGrey.shade50,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 10.0, 8.0, 10.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'untitled header',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 20.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Description (optional)',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  indent: 4.0,
                  endIndent: 4.0,
                  thickness: 2.0,
                ),
                IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.content_copy),
                        iconSize: 24.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text('COpy'),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        iconSize: 24.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        onPressed: this.onDelete,
                      ),
                      VerticalDivider(
                        thickness: 2.0,
                        endIndent: 6.0,
                        indent: 4.0,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                        child: SwitchWidget(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Listview builder

```
body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                FormBuilder(
                    key: widget.fbKey,
                    autovalidate: true,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: widget.data.widgets.length,
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return widget.data.widgets[index];
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

This is how the widget is being added the view is getting changed from selected the widget to List view builder page, when clicked on that particular icon. Where should be the delete function be added, in the List view or in the widget itself ?

```
Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Form Widgets'),
            ),
            body: LayoutBuilder(
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewPointConstrainsts) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: viewPointConstrainsts.maxHeight,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FormWidget(
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              iconData: Icons.title,
                              widgetTxT: 'Header',
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.data.widgets.add(HeaderTextWidget());
                                  widget.pickWidgetsView = false;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Is it where to put delete function?

Comment: @HardikKumar I want to use the delete icon to delete the widget from the Listview , I am unable to get index when I implement delete function on the particular widget.

Comment: How exactly are you creating `widget.data` list to store all the widgets? You should only store data model not the widgets.

Comment: @SanjaySharma yes I do have a model class, which just returns List<Widget> widgets = [];

Comment: Please follow the approach that I explained in answer, you can also post the complete code and I can help you in modification.

Comment: @SanjaySharma I will try it out and will get back to you. Thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: Please mark and upvote the answer if it helps you in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

1. Store only the data, not the `Widget` itself in the list

```dart
List<DataModel> data = []
```

2. Create list view item using `createListViewItem()` which should return widget as the following

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: widget.dataList.length,
  controller: _scrollController,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return createListViewItem(index);
  },
),
```

3. Now inside `createListViewItem(index)` you can create data as per `widget.dataList[index]` and delete the list item on click of delete icon

```dart
setState(){
   widget.dataList.deleteAt(index);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is dataList that you mentioned ?

Comment: It is the list of the data model for creating the list items

Comment: you creating empty list like List<DataModel> data = [ ]; and again creating another dataList of the same model ?

Comment: Replace your widget list with only DataModel list and use it to create list item

Comment: well the error that I am getting is, A value of type 'DataModel' can't be returned from method 'createListViewItems' because it has a return type of 'Widget

Answer (score -1):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          DropdownButton(
            items: _Mothe.map(
              (String dropdownMenuItem) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: dropdownMenuItem,
                  child: Text(dropdownMenuItem),
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              setState(
                () {
                  name == value!;
                },
              );
            },
            value: name,
            isExpanded: true,
            icon: SizedBox(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).